# Solving a matrix which is mostly positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an mxm large sparse matrix representing a system of linear equations. The first nxn elements are a symmetric positive definite matrix. The remaining elements make the matrix no longer symmetric.

Is there a way I can exploit the fact that part of the matrix is SPD to help with finding the solution?

I'm currently using BiCGStab to solve the matrix, but it often fails to converge, so I think my matrix may be poorly conditioned. Any suggestions for useful methodologies or preconditioners would be most welcome.

To give a little more context. m is likely to be of the order 1,000,000, with around 8 nonzero elements per row, except the last two rows which will be close to full. n will be around 999,000. In fact, the top left part is a matrix of size n/2, duplicated twice down the diagonal with the rest of this part being zeros. Here is a diagram to help visualise things. It's not to scale - the not symmetric parts would be invisible if it were.
[image: Matrix diagram]